# C# .Net compact framework porting on linux platform

Tags: c#, .net, linux

we have old application developed using C# .Net compact framework. Right now this application is running on Windows CE. How can we port this to run on linux platform?

Whether this is possible?

Need tools and steps to be followed in porting...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is it depends. Firstly, you would have switch to another UI framework, because .NET Framework does not support other platforms besides Windows. You could take a look at [Avalonia](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/next/get-started/wpf/), it is quite similar to WPF and there is a chance it would only require smaller changes in your project. But again that depends on the application complexity, libraries and external tools used... it might turn out that the application has to be almost completely rewritten.